# Merging dataframe with "in" operator like approach

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge two dataframes. One consists of a "hit" dataframe where I have a number of protein ids. The second is a database dataframe, which contains all known proteins and their functions. See examples below.

The goal is to associate my protein hits with the respective row in the database dataframe. What complicates this is that some of my hits have multiple proteins in one row (Protein_3A; Protein_B below). Is there a way to merge these data frames using an in operation so that the row for protein 3 will be matched as shown in the df below, despite only one of the subtypes (Protein_3B) being present in the database dataframe?

**Example starting dataframes**

```
 hit_df = pd.DataFrame({"Hits": ["Protein_1", "Protein_2", "Protein_3A; Protein_3B", "Protein_8", "Protein_5"]})
        
 database_df = pd.DataFrame({"Proteins": ["Protein_1", "Protein_2", "Protein_3B", "Protein_4", "Protein_9", "Protein10"],"Function": ["FuncX", "FuncY", "FuncZ", "Unknown", "Unkwown", "FuncA"]})
```

**Desired result dataframe**

```
matched_results_df = pd.DataFrame({"Hits":["Protein_1", "Protein_2", "Protein_3B"], "Function":["FuncX", "FuncY", "FuncZ"]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First split each expression according to the **;** symbol on a new row.

```
hit_df= hit_df["Hits"].str.split("; ", expand = False).explode().to_frame()
print(hit_df) 
    Hits
0   Protein_1
1   Protein_2
2   Protein_3A
2   Protein_3B
3   Protein_8
4   Protein_5
```

then use **isin** function and get only matching values.

```
matched_results_df = database_df[database_df['Proteins'].isin(hit_df['Hits'])]
```